Usage of "it" in "imagine if it had been a child…"
This sentence comes from a website:

A man claims he 'could have been killed' after a hit and run on a
"dangerous road."
Adam Williams said he was hit by a moving car as he was bent to
inspect another parked car on Wargrave Road at around 3pm on Saturday
afternoon.
...
"It's massively affected me. There was something on the TV that night
in the background and a car exploded and I jumped off the sofa. I'm
worried about going out and I've not driven since.
'Imagine if it had been a child, there's no way the driver didn't
know they had hit someone or something.'

In this context, does 'it' align more with (from M-W dictionary)
meaning 1: 'that one —used as subject or direct object or indirect object of a verb or object of a preposition usually in reference to a person or animal whose sex is unknown or disregarded
(don't know who it is)
or
meaning 3a: '—often used to shift emphasis to a part of a statement other than the subject (it was in this city that the treaty was signed)'?"
I think the usage is similar to 3a, as if 'that was hit by a moving car' is omitted after 'a child.' Is that correct?"

Clearly #1, referring to the man the car hit in previous sentences and claimed he didn't know he hit anything.

why not he as it refers to a person

Does this answer your question? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/234533/it-this-that-to-refer-to-a-situation

@JavaLatte Yes. Thanks.

@YvesLefol "Is there perhaps a subtle difference in meaning between 'Imagine if it had been a child' and 'Imagine if I had been a child'?"

It is the person (Adam William) who spoke the sentence 'Imagine if it had been a child, there's no way the driver didn't know they had hit someone or something.' Using "he" would be odd as Adam would be referring to himself in the 3rd person. Adam could have used "Imagine if I had been a child". In practical terms It in this case is  referring to the whole situation. It is the incident

A person... whose sex is unknown or disregarded. He is saying "Imagine if the person who was hit had been a child instead of me" - the sex of that imaginary child doesn't matter.

Imagine an ancient king is speaking the following words:

I was so hungry, I just started eating without summoning the royal taster. Imagine if it had been poisoned!

There's no antecedent noun in the utterance, but clearly "it" refers back to the situation and the act of eating the food.
The antecedent of it need not be an explicit noun if the meaning can be "recovered" from the  context.
The "existential" details of the context are available as an interpreting guide.
